# can't install drcsim from source

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When i try this line :  `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim` , it is not working, in terminal after this message:

```
destination directory: drcsim
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
```

nothing happens, inside the drcsim folder i cant see any file or folder, its just empty. Is this happening because my wifi is working slow, or else. I have already installed ros indigo, gazebo 7 and gazebo_ros package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14343/can%27t-install-drcsim-from-source/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It takes a while to download all the files from the repository, so my guess is that this is indeed related to your slow wifi. You must wait until the command fully ends with a message like this:

```
added 4333 changesets with 14277 changes to 6314 files (+111 heads)
updating to branch default
1301 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

You could try cloning a specific branch to reduce the amount of data downloaded. For example, closing only the default branch:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim -b default
```

I got a bit less data than before, but it still took a while to finish:

```
added 3408 changesets with 12985 changes to 6057 files
updating to branch default
1301 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Other packages that you have installed should have no effect in cloning the repository.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3